# How to run previous command by history index in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, command-history

I want to know to how run a previous command in history by index like how it is done in Linux (i.e ![index]).

Yes, F9 in cmd raises a pop up box that allows me to enter in the index, but how do I do it straight form the command-line without the dialog box? Is there a way to do this in cmd without third party downloads?

Additionally, is there a way to display the command history with indexes all well? Moreover, `doskey /history` displays a list of the previously executed commands however it does not list the indexes too.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I do it (run by index) from the command-line without the dialog box?

This is not possible with using a 3-party programs.

You could try using [clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/):

> Clink combines the native Windows shell cmd.exe with the powerful
>   command line editing features of the GNU Readline library, which
>   provides rich completion, history, and line-editing capabilities.
>   Readline is best known for its use in the well-known Unix shell Bash,
>   the standard shell for Mac OS X and many Linux distributions. Features
>
> - The same line editing as Bash (from GNU’s Readline library).
> - History persistence between sessions.
> - Context sensitive completion;
>
>   - Executables (and aliases).
>   - Directory commands.
>   - Environment variables
>   - Thirdparty tools; Git, Mercurial, SVN, Go, and P4.
> - New keyboard shortcuts;
>
>   - Paste from clipboard (Ctrl-V).
>   - Incremental history search (Ctrl-R/Ctrl-S).
>   - Powerful completion (TAB).
>   - Undo (Ctrl-Z).
>   - Automatic “cd ..” (Ctrl-Alt-U).
>   - Environment variable expansion (Ctrl-Alt-E).
>   - (press Alt-H for many more…)
> - Scriptable completion with Lua.
> - Coloured and scriptable prompt.
> - Auto-answering of the “Terminate batch job?” prompt.

---

#### Is there a way to display the command history with indexes?

> `doskey /history` displays a list of the previously executed commands however it does not list the indexes.

Press <kbd>F7</kbd> to list the history with indices:

[image]

You might also want to look at using:

> <kbd>F5</kbd>       Scroll through history of typed commands (↑).
>
> <kbd>F8</kbd>       Move backwards through the command history, but only display
>              commands matching the current text at the command prompt.

Source [syntax-keyboard](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-keyboard.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [syntax-keyboard](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-keyboard.html) - Windows Keyboard shortcuts